# Prove that $ \int_{B_a}f(tx)\,dx=\int_{B_{ta}}f(x)t^{-n}\,dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let , $t$ and $a$ be two positive real numbers. Define , $B_a=\{x=(x_1,\cdots ,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n|x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2 \le a^2\}.$ Then for any compactly supported continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$ which of the followings is(/are) correct ?

(A) $\displaystyle \int_{B_a}f(tx)\,dx=\int_{B_{ta}}f(x)t^{-n}\,dx$.

(B) $\displaystyle \int_{B_a}f(tx)\,dx=\int_{B_{t^na}}f(x)t\,dx$.

(C) $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x+y)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)\,dx$ , for some $y\in \mathbb R^n$.

(D) $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R^n}f(tx)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)t^n\,dx$.

**My Attempt :**

(A) Let , $tx=X$. Then , $x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2 \le a^2$ transformed into $X_1^2+\cdots +X_n^2 \le a^2t^2$ which is $B_{ta}$. Also , $\,dx=t^{-n}\,dX$. So , this option is correct , and option (B) is FALSE. Similarly option (D) is FALSE.

(C) For $y=0=(0,0,\cdots ,0)\in \mathbb R^n$ given relation holds. So this option is correct. In fact he relation holds for arbitrary $y\in \mathbb R^n$.

Am I right or wrong ? .. Please verify.

Comment: Are you sure (C) isn't supposed to ask whether the equality is true for *all* $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$? As it stands it's trivially true.

Comment: NO....' NOT for all $y\in \mathbb R$...'

Comment: Question is correct....According to the question Am I right ?

Comment: @ Joey Zou) As it is true for for all $y\in \mathbb R^n$ so it is obviously TRUE for some $y$. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct. I'm just surprised you're asked to evaluate such a trivial statement...

Comment: @@ Joey Zou) Actually it was a question from a competitive exam. and answer key says only option (A) is correct. So I am confused and ask that...

Comment: May I ask which exam this is, and if there's a link to the questions?

Comment: It was an Indian exam named as CSIR-NET for entrance in P.hd. Sorry question paper will be uploaded after one month (approx.)

Comment: You may wish to contact the exam officials and notify them of this issue then. (I don't know if that's how it works in India, but at least that's what I did when I found an error while taking the GRE in the U.S.)

Comment: I think you are correct @S.Panja-1729